# why site is not redirecting with nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-status-code-301, vesta

I am trying to redirect the domain example.com to another website example.blogspot.com (**which is not hosted in my server**).

I had been using `htaccess` and `cpanel`, so it was easy to redirect. But why redirect is not working in nginx.

No effects seen with following way in the version `nginx/1.15.10` and latest `vesta control panel`,

Still showing the default page (index.html) generated by vesta control panel.  Should I have to change in public_html ? Or restart server ?

I have edited `nginx.conf` with following code.

**method 1**

```
http{
    server{
        listen          80;
        server_name     example.com www.example.com;
        return          301 https://example.blogspot.com$request_uri;
    }
    .....
}
```

**method 2**

```
http{
    server{
        listen [::]:80;
        listen          80;
        server_name     example.com www.example.com;
        return          301 https://example.blogspot.com$request_uri;
    }
    .....
}
```

**method 3**

```
http{
    server { 
        server_name .example.com;
        return 301 $scheme://example.blogspot.com;
    }
    ....

}
```

restarting ngix after save

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, adding `Server Ip address` with listen port redirect domain

```
http{
    server{
        listen          my.server.ip.address:80;
        server_name     example.com www.example.com;
        return          301 https://example.blogspot.com$request_uri;
    }
    .....
}
```